# Solving trigonometric equations simultaneously

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I wonder if the following equations
$$ \begin{cases}
    -\pi (k-x) \sin(2 \pi x) + x \sin x - (x - 2 \pi (k-x) ) \sin(x(2 \pi-1) ) =0  \\
   3 + \cos(2 \pi x) - 2 \cos x -  2 \cos(x(2 \pi-1) ) +\\
    +2 \pi (k-x) \left[-\sin(2 \pi x) + 2 \sin(x(2 \pi-1) )\right]    =0
\end{cases}$$
are fulfilled simultaneously for some $k\in\mathbb Z$, i.e. whether they have common solution ($x$) for some $k\in\mathbb Z$. It seems to be a very difficult task.

---

EDIT: Thanks to comments, we can note that $x=0$ is a solution of both equations. Then we rewrite the question in this way: to search a common solution ($x\neq0$) for some $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Are you asking whether there is some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that the two equations then have a common solution (value of $x$)? Something else?

Comment: @rogerl: Yes, I've edited my post to better explain the ask.

Comment: Surely there exists some $k$ such that the system of equations has a solution; choose any $k$, then $x=0$ is a solution.

Comment: @Meneer-Beer: thank you! I didn't notice it. I wonder if there is a solution $x=x(k)$ that can satisfies both equations. Maybe yes, but it is quite intractable.

Comment: have you graphed it?